# Passing string in an onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable `VISIT_ID` that containing value including space as `Visit 1`. I have passed this variable in the below `onclick` function. This return statement is used inside the `javascript datatable column`.

```
var Cols = [
    {
        "mData": "VISIT_ID", "sDefaultContent": "", "mRender": function (data, type, index, row) {
            return data;
        }
    },
    {
    "mData": "ALERT_ACTION", "sDefaultContent": "", "mRender": function (data, type, index, row) {
        return "<label>Not Reviewed</label><i onclick = OpenAlert('" + index.VISIT_ID + "') data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top'></i>";
     }
];
```

But while clicking on it. I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

When I console this method. I get the result as this:

```
OpenAlertActionOverlay('Visit 1')
```

But if we console `event.target`, its result is coming as:

[image]

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    console.log('event.target', event.target);
}
```

Comment: The output doesn't seem to match the code? `OpenAlert('" + index.VISIT_ID + "')` shouldn't output `OpenAlert('Visit" 1')` (where is the first `"`?)

Comment: Agreed with @evolutionxbox : https://jsfiddle.net/0ta4v875/

Comment: @evolutionxbox, this double quotes is coming during runtime only. Can check output of this `console.log('event.target', event.target);`

Comment: @Lim you said that `I have a variable VISIT_ID that containing value including space as Visit 1.`. then why you are using `index.VISIT_ID`? why not directly using `VISIT_ID`

Comment: Opening double quotes will be in front of the method name. And its closing is coming after the space in the parameter value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be due to unaccounted use of `'` or `"`. To avoid keeping track of all these quotes you can use [Template_literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
return `<label>Not Reviewed</label>
        <i onclick = OpenAlert("${index.VISIT_ID}") 
           data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top'>
        </i>`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to mash strings together to form something with JavaScript inside HTML using JavaScript is **hard** and **fragile**. Avoid doing it if at all possible.

Both standard DOM and jQuery have tools for generating DOM objects: Use them!

You code will be more verbose, but a lot more readable.

```js
...function (data, type, index, row) {

  function openAlert() {
    openAlert($(this).data('visit-id'));
  }

  const label = jQuery("<label />").text("Not reviewed");
  const italic = jQuery("<i />")
    .on("click", openAlert)
    .data("toggle", "tooltop")
    .data("placement", "top")
    .data("visit-id", index.VISIT_ID);

  const wrapper = jQuery(<div />);
  wrapper.append(label, italic);

  return wrapper;
}
```

---

Asides:

- `<label>`s are for labeling `<input>`s and other form controls. You have no `for` attribute and there's no form control inside it. You're using the wrong element.
- `<i>` elements are for marking text which would typically be rendered in print as italic (e.g. names of ships). You have no text. I'm guessing you plan to put a background image there, but that is wildly unhelpful for a variety of people (including keyboard users and screen reader users).  It looks like that should be a `<button>` containing an `<img>` with an `alt` attribute.